# Don't Accuse Me Of Being One!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Color me true,
>   But don't call me blue.
>   Roast me if you care,
>   Though grab my coat if you dare.
>   They find me throughout,
>   Delicious, don't you doubt.

Comment: This riddle got me *out of the blue* :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't Accuse Me Of Being One!

> Chestnut - this is an original riddle so shouldn't call you this.

Color me true,

> Chestnut is a reddish-brown colour.

But don't call me blue.

> A [chestnut](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/chestnut?s=t) as a ha-ha joke so not sad or adult (but too old).

Roast me if you care,

> Chestnuts roasting on an open fire.

Though grab my coat if you dare.

> Chestnuts (especially the horse) have a prickly coat.

They find me throughout,

> Chestnut meaning commonplace (conker sounds like conquer).

Delicious, don't you doubt.

> Sweet chestnuts.

Comment: Tom, this was a great answer; I learned quite a few new things here. +1

Comment: You got it! Will give the tick tomorrow.

Answer (score 9):

Are you a

> Marshmallow?

Color me true,

> You roast them.

But don't call me blue.

> There can be blue flames in the fire you roast them in, or blue can mean sadness and marshmallows are pretty cheery.

Roast me if you care,

> It is the best way to eat them.

Though grab my coat if you dare.

> It is hot!

They find me throughout,

> In a s'more.

Delicious, don't you doubt.

> Almost solid sugar.

Title

> maybe a softy because marshmallows are soft?

Comment: I'm not sure about the coat, since in my experience that is the only thing to grab...

Answer (score 7):

Is it:

> **Corn**?
> Hopi maize is known as blue corn.
> It can be roasted.
> Its outer layer ("coat") is quite thick so it would be tough to grab it.
> Corn is pretty ubiquitous.
> It is also quite delicious.
> Plus, no one likes to be called "corny"!

Answer (score 6):

Are you a:

> Waffle?

Don't Accuse me of being one!

> Waffle is an insult meaning brainless/dumb

Color me true

> There is tons of recipes for "True Belgian Waffles" etc.

But don't call me blue

> Don't google that (NSFW), as it is a rather unpleasently looking disease

Roast me if you care

> Waffles can indeed be prepared by roasting them.

Though grab my coat if you dare

> Waffles (Belgian Waffles in particular I believe) are often coated in sugar

They find me throughout

> Waffles are not only found everywhere (almost every household has one person 
> Knowing how they are prepared due to their recipes simplicity)
> There are also a LOT of different waffles throughout the world: American, Belgian, Liège, Hong Kong Waffles, etc. There are even variations like waffle cones for ice cream.

Delicious, don't you doubt.

> Waffles are a staple in almost every country's breakfeast regiment. They are simply delicious.

First time posting on any SE, so I hope I didn't mess up the spoiler feature

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This is a great answer! I especially enjoyed your reasoning behind *They find me throughout*. Please feel free to [take-the-tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) as with all SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a

> Chicken

?

Color me true
But don't call me blue

> To be "Chicken" is to be "Yellow", not "Blue"

Roast me if you care
Though grab my coat if you dare

> Roast chicken is delicious, but fresh out of the oven the skin will be very hot!

They find me throughout

> Chickens are found worldwide

Delicious, don't you doubt

> Roast chicken is delicious

But, most of all:
Don't Accuse Me Of Being One!

> [Nobody - Calls - Me - Chicken!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-D54nRdWwik)

Comment: *Though grab my coat if you dare*; not going to lie, as I read your answer I was completely expecting rot13(unir lbh rire gevrq gb chyy n puvpxra'f srnguref). :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Lobster/Crab?

Color me true

> Lobsters turn red when cooked

But don't call me blue

> Some lobsters are blue prior to being cooked

Roast me if you care

> You can roast a lobster to prepare it

Though grab my coat if you dare

> I think this refers to either the lobster snapping at you while alive or removing it's shell when dead.

They find me throughout

> People hunt lobsters in many places

Delicious, don't you doubt.

> Some people even seem to enjoy eating lobsters apparently

Title

> Generic Person seems to be in a crabby mood